# How to make generated matrix non-repeating in Python?

Tags: python

We have created a matrix that is a random size, and has random digits, but we aren't sure how to make sure that none of the generated strings are the same. For reference, we need the matrix to be non-repeating because we're trying to calculate the recursive teaching dimension -- basically a complexity measurement of data sets -- of the set of all the strings and it can't be computed if any of the strings are the same.

An example of a matrix generated is:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 0 0]]
```

As you can see, the second and third strings and the first and last strings are identical.

This is our current code. How should we go about ensuring that nothing repeats?

```
def matrix():
  import numpy as np
  import random

  a = random.randrange (2, 10)
  b = random.randrange (2, a)

  A = np.random.randint(2, size=(a,b))
  print (A)

matrix()
```

Comment: As far as I understand, your requierment adds a restriction to the size. For example, if `b` is `3` like in your example, then `a` must be `<= 8` (2^3)

Comment: There are only 2^b different *strings* possible, so if a > 2^b there must be repetitions.

Comment: How about first creating a matrix which goes through all iterations of set bits (000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111) and then shuffle the rows randomly, eventually also deleting rows randomly if the required dimension differs?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not fixated on `numpy`, here is an option using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html)' [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)'s [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```py
import itertools
import random

b = random.randrange (2, 10)
a = random.randrange (2, 2**b)

words = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=b))

matrix = random.sample(words, a)

print(matrix)
```

Running with fixed values of `b=3` and `a=7` gives:

```
[(1, 0, 1), 
 (0, 1, 0), 
 (0, 1, 1), 
 (1, 0, 0), 
 (1, 1, 1), 
 (1, 1, 0), 
 (0, 0, 1)]
```

---

Note that [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns tuples, so if that matters, a simple conversion is needed:

```py
words = [list(tup) for tup in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=b)]
```

Comment: Ah, of course, *itertools*! I new there is an easier way

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to choose *a* different numbers between zero and *2^b-1*
and use their binary representations as the different strings in *A*.

```
import numpy as np
a = random.randrange (2, 10)
b = random.randrange (2, a)

# Choos numbers between 0 and the largest representable number with b digits
nums_base_ten = np.random.choice(np.arange(2**b-1), a, replace=False)

print(nums)

A = np.zeros((a, b))

# Loop over digits and generate the binary representation for the chosen numbers
# Fill in ones if necessary to represent the numbers, reduce, repeat
for i in range(b):
    temp_value_base2 = 2**(b-1-i)
    bool_digit = nums >= temp_value_base2
    A[:, i] = bool_digit
    nums[bool_digit] -= temp_value_base2

print(A)
```